# Head value set to null but tail value still gets displayed

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In java linked lists if head=null then the LinkedList is empty. However when I set head=null and print value of tail the value is displayed. Why is it that we say head==null means that the LinkedList is empty? Why is tail value being displayed when the linked list should be empty? Shouldn't we check id(tail==null)as well?

```
public class SinglyLinkedList{
  public Node head;
  public Node tail;
  public int size;

  public Node createLL(int num){
    Node node=new Node();
    node.value=num;
    node.next=null;
    head=node;
    tail=node;

    size=1;
    return head;
  }

  public void insertNode(int num,int location){
    Node node=new Node();
    node.value=num;
    
    if(head==null){//Check
      createLL(num);
      return;
    }

    else if(location==0){
      node.next=head;
      head=node;
    }

    else if(location>=size){
      node.next=null;
      tail.next=node;
      tail=node;
    }

    else{
      Node tempNode=head;
      int index=0;

      while(index<location-1){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
        index++;
      }
     node.next=tempNode.next;
     tempNode.next=node;
    }
    size++;
  }

  public void traverse(){
    if(head==null){//Check
      System.out.println("The linked list is empty");
    }
    Node tempNode=head;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      System.out.print(tempNode.value);
      if(i!=size-1){
        System.out.print("->");
      }
      tempNode=tempNode.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  public void deleteNode(int location){
    if(head==null){//Check
      System.out.println("The linked list is not present");
      return;
    }

    else if(location==0){
      head=head.next;
      size--;
      if(size==0){
        tail=null;
      }
    }

    else if(location>=size){
      Node tempNode=head;
      for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
      }
      if(head==null){
        tail=null;
        size--;
        return;
      }
      tempNode.next=null;
      tail=tempNode;
      size--;
    }

    else{
      Node tempNode=head;
      int index=0;

      while(index<location-1){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
        index++;
      }
      tempNode.next=tempNode.next.next;
      size--;
    }
  }
```

Main class

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SinglyLinkedList sLL=new SinglyLinkedList();
    sLL.createLL(5);
    sLL.insertNode(15, 1);
    sLL.insertNode(20, 2);
    sLL.insertNode(39, 3);
    sLL.insertNode(45, 4);

    sLL.traverse();
    
    sLL.head=null;
    System.out.println(sLL.tail.value);
  }
}
```

Output:
5->15->20->39->45

45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`head` being `null` just means that you cannot reach the first `Node` anymore. This also implies that you cannot access the whole chain via the `next` reference, since you've no starting point.
The garbage collector is allowed to "free" all objects which aren't reachable anymore. In your case all nodes except the `tail` Node, since you still keep a reference to it in your `SinglyLinkedList`.

So in fact you've an kind-of empty LinkedList, since you cannot correctly access it anymore. But you still keep the `tail` node alive, since you reference it. The correct solution would be to set `tail` to `null` as well, so the garbage collector can also free this node.

Comment: In insert node and delete node, I have checked if(head==null). If this is true it means that the LinkedList is empty and it returns. However, shouldn't it be if(head==null && tail==null)? Why is it that we only check head as tail still points to the last node after we set head=null? Isn't tail->node also not a LinkedList?

Comment: @2019079925 The assumption can be that the list is empty when head is null. But it's not consistent to keep the tail pointing at the "old" end node. Just clear it also up and you are good to go. You are currently simply remembering the last end node you had. This information is of no use when the linked list is no longer there

Comment: How do I clear it up? Do I write if(head==null) set tail=null. Where should I put this code?

Comment: @2019079925 Usually you'd have a clear method, similar to the [official API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#clear()). The `tail` reference is simply a helper that is no longer valid nor necessary when you set the `head` to null. Hence you must set it to `null` when you clear the list itself (by setting `head` to null).

Comment: @2019079925 You can have a look at the openjdk implementation [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java). The relevant part is `first = last = null;` in `clear()`. `last` is your `tail`. It's helpful for adding nodes, but is no longer valid when you cleared your LinkedList.

Comment: This is my final doubt. How do I use this in my code? How do I create and call a method that sets tail=null whenever head becomes null?

Comment: @2019079925. You can't. What you do is setting `head` and `tail` as `private`. Then you provide a `public` method it clear it. No-one using your class will be able to directly manipulate `tail` or `head`. All they can do is call `clear` and other public methods. And in these methods you (the programmer of the linked list) make sure that everything is consistent afterwards.

Comment: So, I just make head and tail field private, add a clear() method and I no longer have to worry about if(head==null) condition? Please help.

Comment: @2019079925: You make it private, but you'll still need to check at the relevant places. Assume I call `clear()` and then `traverse()`. You'd still want the output `isEmpty` (as it is in your current logic). The advantage is that you can set `tail` to null directly when someone calls `clear`. And no-one from the outside can directly manipulate `head` or `tail`

Comment: Ok, so instead of head==null I replace it with isEmpty. Right?

Comment: @2019079925 Up to you, you can check for null or put that check in another method and call that instead. What remains from the original question is that nothing will "Magically" set `tail` to null. That's something you have to do in order to have a correct logic. And to enforce it, you provide a public API where no method leaves the LinkedList in an inconsistent state

Answer (score 0):

By that assignment you make your list instance inconsistent. An empty list would have *both* its `head` and `tail` member set to `null` **and** its `size` equal to 0.

That's why you should not just alter a member of your class like that. You should probably even make them private to prevent the caller from doing such manipulations. If you want to have a way to empty a list, then create a proper method for it, which takes care of keeping the properties consistent:

```
public void clear() {
    head = tail = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

And in your main code, just call that `sLL.clear()` method.

If you keep a reference to a node, you will always be able to access it. To really *lose* a node, you must get rid of *all* references to it.

Comment: In insert node and delete node, I have checked if(head==null). If this is true it means that the LinkedList is empty and it returns. However, shouldn't it be if(head==null && tail==null)? Why is it that we only check head as tail still points to the last node after we set head=null? Isn't tail->node also not a LinkedList?

Comment: No, it is OK as it is. You must assume that the list is consistent, i.e. when `head` is `null` it follows that `tail` is `null`. This consistency must be maintained by all operations executed on the list, and that is why I propose to make these members private, so that only the class methods are responsible for manipulating these members, and can at the same time guarantee their consistency.

Comment: So every time `head` is set to `null`, also `tail` should be set to `null`. This should be imposed by your code. If ever you have the situation that `head` is `null` and `tail` is not, you have an inconsistency, and that must be avoided.

Comment: This is the thing that I don't understand "head is null it follows that the tail is null". How is it that when the head becomes null tail automatically becomes null? Where is this given in the above code? This is a code from a Udemy course that I am learning so please be understanding.

Comment: I am not saying it *automatically* becomes `null`. I am saying that the code of this class is *responsible* for doing all that is necessary that this invariant is maintained. So it should not be allowed that any code out there just decides to assign `null` to `head`. This should not be allowed, as indeed then `tail` will still be a node reference (and also `size` would not be reset to 0, so also that would be inconsistent).

Comment: How do I make my code consistent? Do I write if(head==null) set tail=null. Where should I put this code?

Comment: I thought I had answered that question: you add a method (called `clear` for example) which takes all three actions, so that they remain consistent. And don't allow the main code to directly access `head` or `tail` or `size`, but make methods (like `clear`) to manipulate the list. The main code should only call methods of the linked list instance. That way the methods can always ensure consistency between these three properties.