# Set tail=null when head=null in singly linked list in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In java singly LinkedList how do I write code that nulls the tail(tail=null) when I null the head(head=null)? I am a beginner and hence find it difficult. I have included if(head==null)in every method but also want to  implement code that sets tail=null when head=null so as to avoid a bug.
Here is my code

```
public class SinglyLinkedList{
  public Node head;
  public Node tail;
  public int size;


  public Node createLL(int num){
    Node node=new Node();
    node.value=num;
    node.next=null;
    head=node;
    tail=node;

    size=1;
    return head;
  }

  public void insertNode(int num,int location){
    Node node=new Node();
    node.value=num;
    
    if(head==null){
      createLL(num);
      return;
    }

    if(location==0){
      node.next=head;
      head=node;
    }

    else if(location>=size){
      node.next=null;
      tail.next=node;
      tail=node;
    }

    else{
      Node tempNode=head;
      int index=0;

      while(index<location-1){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
        index++;
      }
     node.next=tempNode.next;
     tempNode.next=node;
    }
    size++;
  }

  public void traverse(){
    if(head==null){
      System.out.println("The linked list is empty");
    }
    Node tempNode=head;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      System.out.print(tempNode.value);
      if(i!=size-1){
        System.out.print("->");
      }
      tempNode=tempNode.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  public boolean searchElement(int num){
    Node tempNode=head;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      if(tempNode.value==num){
        System.out.println("The value is present at index:"+i);
        return true;
      }
      tempNode=tempNode.next;
    }
    System.out.println("The value is not present");
    return false;
  }

  public void deleteNode(int location){
    if(head==null){
      System.out.println("The linked list is not present");
      return;
    }

    else if(location==0){
      head=head.next;
      size--;
      if(size==0){
        tail=null;
      }
    }

    else if(location>=size){
      Node tempNode=head;
      for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
      }
      if(head==null){
        tail=null;
        size--;
        return;
      }
      tempNode.next=null;
      tail=tempNode;
      size--;
      
      head=tail=null;
    }

    else{
      Node tempNode=head;
      int index=0;

      while(index<location-1){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
        index++;
      }
      tempNode.next=tempNode.next.next;
      size--;
    }
  }

  public void deleteSinglyLinkedList(){
    if(head==null){
      System.out.println("The linkedlist is absent");
    }
    head=tail=null;
    System.out.println("The entire linked list has been deleted");
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(head == null) tail = null;` or(equvalent): `if(head == null) tail = head;`;)

Comment: Where should I place this code in my program in order for it work on all operations like insertion, deletion ,traversal and search?

Comment: Please add more details to your question! Please also have a look at [mre] and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70642813/head-value-set-to-null-but-tail-value-still-gets-displayed), you should better add a method to your class that takes care of the clearing, and not let the main code change the value of `head` directly.

Comment: You also forget that there is a third dependency: `size`. If `head` is set to `null`, you must also set the `size` to 0. You should not allow any code outside your class to modify these members one by one. You should insist that the main code only uses methods to manipulate the list, or read its size. These methods should then make sure that if they change one thing, they also make the consistent change to the other fields. It should then never be necessary to check that `tail` is `null` when `head` is `null`, because your methods would guarantee that rule to be never violated.

Answer (score 0):

After a few comments, edits and going over your code, I would like you to look into your `deleteNode()` method. You might have encountered problems since you check for `head==null` *before* the actual removal of a node, I commented on problematic lines:

```
public void deleteNode(int location){
    if(head==null){
      System.out.println("The linked list is not present");
      return;
    }
    else if(location==0){
      head=head.next;
      size--;
      if(size==0){
        tail=null;
      }
    }
    else if(location>=size){
      Node tempNode=head;
      for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
      }
      if(head==null){ // This is a good check, however -
        tail=null;    // it should be written after the removal line.
        size--;       // Also, this check shouldn't reduce size any further.
        return;       // <- this return also stops the method from actually removing a node.
      }
      tempNode.next=null; // this is the actual removal line.
      tail=tempNode;
      size--;
      
      head=tail=null;    // potentialy problematic line - 
    }                    // seems to set both head and tail to null, why?

    else{
      Node tempNode=head;
      int index=0;

      while(index<location-1){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
        index++;
      }
      tempNode.next=tempNode.next.next;
      size--;
    }
  }
```

If you would move the `if (head..` to work *after* ```tempNode.next = null``, you shouldn't encounter times where the head is null and the tail is not.

Here is how the `if (location>=size)` should look after changes:

```
    else if(location>=size){
      Node tempNode=head;
      for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
      }

      tempNode.next=null; 
      tail=tempNode;
      size--;

      if(head==null){
        tail=null;    
      }
    }
```